# Can I add "min" and "max" properties to the "location" property?

Tags: python, scripting, properties

In my first Blender script, I'm asking how can I control the slider value with min and max values without using FloatProperty.

```
box1 = layout.box()
box1.label("Span (Z) profiles positions:")
box1.prop(obj, "location", index = 2, text = "Span")
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the documentation, I do not think there is a built-in option for an object's location (some other Blender values may be, but you could check on [Blender's API docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html)).  It would be best to use a FloatProperty or FloatVectorProperty.  You could use a setter so it updates the object's location whenever the value changes, but that would also require some way to keep track of the object for the property.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will see in details the blender's API docs. If I found that is possible to do it, it will be more easy for me  because I used FloatPoperty in my program but the values are not apdated ! I always look first for the easiest solution.